# iOS: Cannot get push notification to work on one particular device

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios8.2

I have set up push notification on my app by following the tutorial on the [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringPushNotifications/ConfiguringPushNotifications.html), and I got push notification to work on all but one device. For this particular device, neither the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` nor the `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` methods are being called. All the devices I've tested are running iOS 8.2 and I'm using XCode 6.2.

Here are the steps that I've already tried to resolve the issue:

- Deleting and re-installing my app on this device
- Re-booting the device
- Deleting all provisioning profiles on the device (Settings > General > Profiles)

Has anyone run into a similar issue in the past? And if so, could you share how you were able to resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a provisioning issue. That's all I can guess without much more information.

Comment: Here is a debugging option. Try to programmatically change your app icon's badge number and see if it works. If not, what error log does it show?

Comment: @n00bProgrammer, thank you so much for the debugging option! It actually helped me resolving my issue. After I attempted to change my app icon's badge number it didn't work and I got this error "Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received permission from the user to badge the application". As it turned out the Badge App Icon was disabled in the notification center. Once I enabled it, the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken got called. Now even if I disable the Badge App Icon notification, I still get the remote remote notification token. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Please enable the push notifications on appid.And register the application for push notifications.

And please check your device settings disabled or enabled the notifications for your application.

Comment: The OP has specified that the notifications do not work on a specific device. None of the points you have mentioned address that.

Comment: for that particular device u can check the notification settings on device.I think this one is useful one

Comment: @GsrIos, thanks for the suggestion. I did try to toggle the notification setting on this device but that did not resolve the issue.